# Why can't I find the entry point?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, interop, activex

I've got one third-party dll library which I have to work with.
The following pretty simple delphi code does the job:

```
var
 CCPActiveX:variant;
begin
 CCPActiveX:=CreateOleObject('CCP.CCPActiveX');
 CCPActiveX.CCP_Init('arg1','arg2');
 //...
 CCPActiveX:=unassigned;
end;
```

However I'd love to have the samething work on C#. I tried to import dll methods like this:

```
class CCP
{
    [DllImport("CCP.dll")]
    private static extern int CCP_Init(string arg1, string arg2);

    public static int Init(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        return CCP_Init(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

However it results into *Can't find DLL entry point* exception.

I also tried to specify the entry point differently, say:

1. `[DllImport("CCP.dll", EntryPoint = "CCP.CCPActiveX.CCP_Init")]`
2. `[DllImport("CCP.dll", EntryPoint = "CCPActiveX.CCP_Init")]`

and so on. But nothing changed.

I tested delphi code on Windows xp x86. And the C# code - on Windows 7 x64. On both OSs the dll is sucessfully registered with regsvr32.exe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's just not how COM works. The DLL does not export a function named `CCP_Init`. The functions that it exports are, at a minimum, `DllCanUnloadNow, DllGetClassObject, DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer`